# JS: How to mock a nested function in a jestJS unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

How do I mock a nested `console.error` in a jest unit test?

With my attempt (see below) I do get the error `jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy. Received: undefined`

**Function**

```
_onSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const { username, password } = this.state

  return this.props.createUserMutation({
    variables: { username, password }
  }).then(response => {
    const token = response.data.createUser.token
    if (token) {
      // do something
    } else {
      console.error('No token recieved')
    }
  })
}
```

**Test**

```
it('_onSubmit() should log error, if no token is recieved', (done) => {
  console['error'] = jest.fn()

  const createUserMutation = () => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      data: {
        createUser: { token: undefined }
      }
    })
  }
  const wrapper = shallow(<CreateAccount
    createUserMutation={createUserMutation}
  />)

  wrapper
    .update()
    .find(Form)
    .props()
    .onSubmit({ preventDefault: () => {} })
    .then(() => {
      expect(console.error()).toHaveBeenCalledWith('No token recieved')
      done()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, you're calling the function `console.error` instead of passing the function to expect, that's why you get undefined, since this fn won't return anything:

`expect(console.error()).toHaveBeenCalledWith('No token recieved')`

Instead of the result, you want to pass the function itself like so:

`expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith('No token recieved')`

Also, since you're trying to mock the global console function, you'll probably have to change your mock setup to something along the lines of:

`global.console.error = jest.fn()`

Comment: When do I have to mock for the global? As now the code is working - without using global...

Comment: Alright, good to know it worked like that for you! Depending on how the modules are loaded it's possible that you're just overwriting the console.log in the current scope.